# Were there any Frankish/French kings who probably had no extramarital sexual relations?

Tags: france, monarchy, sexuality

I was listening to Dan Carlin's podcast about the start of Merovingian dynasty, and he made a snide quip about the early Merovingians (starting with Clovis) and even Carolingians not exactly being paragons of Christian morality - including having official concubines.

We also know that many later French kings in 16th+ century clearly had mistresses (*I'm excluding Louis XIII who everyone and their grandmother thinks was homosexual or at least bi, and had male lovers even if he had no known female mistresses*).

**Were there any French kings who probably had no extramarital sexual relations**? (e.g. who were renowned among their contemporaries for their "chastity," as opposed to merely not having proof to the contrary).

I'm doing this according to Catholic doctrine, so divorcing and re-marrying counts as "extramarital" - so *[Philip I the Amorous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_I_of_France)* doesn't count even if he married Bertrade de Montfort.

Also, someone who was actually married and of an age/position to have extramarital affairs is a working assumption here.

Comment: I'm not sure how we could possibly know this.

Comment: @T.E.D. - Some sources (ideally, independent ones and not the king's official biographer) stating that the king was faithful to his wife, and nobody ever rumoured about any mistresses?

Comment: It isn't that I can't imagine a source saying that. The problem is that I can't imagine any such source that could possibly be both knowledgeable enough about a king's private activities to make blanket statements about what he'd never ever done during his own private time, and independent enough to be trustworthy.

Comment: @T.E.D. - I'm not all that well read on earlier kings, but for the later ones it seems a slam dunk "no" in that every one of them has tons of sources confirming the mistresses. Sleazy tabloids and celebrity watching didn't seem to originate in 20th century :)

Comment: John I the Posthumous reigned from the age of 0 to 5 days. I'd make this an answer, but I don't think it's what you're going for.

Comment: @twosheds - I actually considered mentioning that scenario in the question as ineligible explicitly, but yes, the assumption is that it's someone who was in a position to have such affairs.

Comment: How would you know this? Reliable source? Like what, his mother in law?

Comment: It would probably be a lot easier to prove that every single Frankish screwed every wench he could lay his hands on.

Comment: @TylerDurden - THAT. I'm quite prepared for the answer that basically lists every king and a source indicating proof that they had sexual relations with that woman, Ms. ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unanswerable.

Comment: -1 as totally unknowable!

Comment: Could we change the question from "definitely unknowable" to "Which Frankish King is most likely to have been chaste?"

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - then people will downvote because comparing "more or less chaste" is subjective (which it kinda is). Also, considering the answer, it seems pretty knowable.

Comment: @TylerDurden - shouldn't the fact that it produced a great answer tell you something about your correctness (never mind rude comments?)

Comment: I changed "definitely" to "probably" and nominate the question for re-opening in its current form. While nothing is definite, these things can be "proved" by "preponderance of evidence."

Comment: @DVK The "answer" is not a response to the original question, which has been heavily edited to change its meaning. Louix IX was not a Carolingian or Merovingian king, the original focus of the question. Also, the original question demanded certainty. Also, the Carolingian and Merovingian dynasties were highly promiscuous cultures as Dan Carlin apparently has pointed out. Changing the question so that it no longer requires proof and allows ANY French king from ANY dynasty is a completely different question and does not somehow invalidate my earlier comments which were to the original question.

Comment: @TylerDurden - reading comprehension problems? Carolingians anjd Merovingians were the subject of the podcast that was the reason I thought of asking the question. The question itself (very conveniently bolded) didn't limit the timelines, and I pretty clearly included later dynasties since it mentioned Louis XIII.

Comment: @DVK Yes, I realize that, but the emphasis seemed to be on the Carlin-mentioned dynasties.

Comment: @TylerDurden - (and Philip I  was not a Carolingian either)

Comment: @TylerDurden - emphasis was very clearly stated by bolding the actual question. That bolded question did NOT include any time or dynastic limits. You read a peface and decided to misapply it to the whole question for some reason, contrary to the rest of the information in the post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fortunately, Wikipedians maintain a list of French royal mistresses, so we can knock off a whole slew of Kings at once ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_French_royal_mistresses)). The list starts with Clovis I and ends with Napoleon III: the A-Z of French royal infidelity.

Any king not on that list is a candidate for having been a faithful husband. I'll suggest that Saint Louis IX was among the most likely to have been faithful. [Discussions of his sex life](https://books.google.com/books?id=MpDiGKG4FSsC&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=%22louis%20ix%22%20chaste&source=bl&ots=Da5ZzAEJbe&sig=csCA5RRZtoqvMRhvpFzxVfekIb4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mrSVVNP4KfD9sATugoHgDg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22louis%20ix%22%20chaste&f=false) suggest that although he loved his wife and had eleven children with her, he was still pretty good with self-control:

> If one were to pass judgment on the marital life of Louis IX, one
>   could say without reservation that it fulfilled all the requirements
>   made by Pope Piux XI in his encyclical on marriage, *Casti connubii*.
>   It was a chaste marriage, in which there was no misuse of the marriage
>   right . . . Ever since their youth they had faithfully practiced
>   marital continence . . . The biographers explicitly report that they
>   observed continence during the so-called "days of abstinence" in the
>   liturgical year, in Advent and Lent, also on Friday and Saturday of
>   each week, and, furthermore, for one day before and one day after the
>   reception of Holy Communion . . . It goes without saying that sexual
>   abstinence was also practiced in the marriage whenever the wife was
>   pregnant . . .

After lots of Googling and Google book-searching, I haven't found any mention of courtesans, affairs, or mistresses associated with Louis IX. Given the amount of historiographical interest in Louis IX, and given that biographers were apparently familiar with his sex life, Louis IX seems as "probably chaste" as any of the other French kings left off that list.

Answer (score 1):

King Louis VII was probably one such king. His first wife, Eleanor of [Acquitaine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleanor_of_Aquitaine) (in)famously complained that he was "more of a monk than a man." When they got married (as teenagers), he donated her wedding gift, a valuable rock crystal vase, to the St. Denis Basilica (church).